# Java FX Delete TreeView root item

Tags: javafx, treeview, javafx-8

In my app I need to be able to remove every item from TreeView.

I have my TreeView injected i controller

```
private @FXML TreeView<Component> treeView;
```

My deletion code:

```
private void deleteSelectedNode() {
    TreeItem<Component> node = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }

    TreeItem<Component> parent = node.getParent();

    if (parent != null) {
        parent.getChildren().remove(node);
    } else {
        //how to delete root item without parent?           
    }
}
```

Actual question is: how to remove root element? I could not find any method in api and I don't want to create new instance, I prefer dependency injection solution.
I think I can hide this item untill next node is created, but it seems to be little hacky.

Thank you for your time spent in this topic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
treeView.setRoot(null);
```

should work.

Comment: Oh, I thought it ends up with some exceptions thrown, but I needed nullcheck in selection change handler -_- Of course it works, Thank you very much!